# Do not display 'user login' block

Tags: drupal-6

I do not want the user login block to be displayed for users who are not admin.

I only want it to be displayed for the admin user (sitadmin, uid:1, in my case) and users who are not logged in (uid:0)

In the configure page (/admin/build/block/configure/user/0) for the block, under page specific settings, I have selected "Show if the following PHP code returns TRUE (PHP-mode, experts only)." and given the following code:

```
<?php
global $user;

if($user->uid===1 or $user->uid===0)
  return TRUE;
else
  return FALSE;

?>
```

However, it is still visible even for users with uid 3,4 etc. I have tried clearing cache, with no avail. On the other hand, if I simply put

```
<?php return FALSE;?>
```

The user block is not shown for anonymous users.

Note: Role specific visibility settings do not seem to have an effect on this.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "user log in block" as the user log in block doesn't appear for logged in users. Logged in users see the link to log out, and if you are removing that, they will not be able to log out (which is not a good idea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it also could be that in the `$user` array, uid is actually a string. so when you give it the `===` it tries to compare type as well. you could either do `$user->uid==="1"` or `$user->uid==1`

EDIT:

you could also try checking their user roles with

`!in_array('authenticated user', array_values($user->roles))`.

i think that's the logic you want. I'm not sure you're defining anything other than standard behavior for the login block... it only shows up if someone is NOT logged in? How is that different from normal?

Comment: well, if that's the case then I should always get FALSE irrespective of the user. But that's not the case! Anyways, I tried that; no luck.

Comment: My bad. :( I had imagined the 'user login' and 'navigation' block to be the same! I wanted the navigation visible only for admin users and not for others. So I move that code for 'navigation' block visibility, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   
global $user;

if($user->uid==1 || $user->uid==0)
  return TRUE;
else
  return FALSE;
 ?>
```

would do the trick.

If you're unsure, always do a simple echo and display the block. For example:

```
<?php   
global $user;

if($user->uid==1)
  echo "Hello world!";
 ?>
```